# Special Relativity - Matrix Notation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Suppose we have a vector $A^\mu$. This vector has 4 components (0 through 3). If we consider the Lorentz's transformation of each component, we could simplify them into matrix notation, ${A^\prime}^\mu=L^\mu{}_{\nu} A^\nu$, where:

$$L^\mu{}_{\nu}= 
\left(
\begin {matrix}\gamma & -v\gamma & 0 & 0\\
-v\gamma & \gamma & 0 & 0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

where $\gamma=(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Knowing that $A_{\mu}= \eta_{\mu\nu} A^\nu$ and

$$\eta_{\mu\nu}= \left(
\begin{matrix} -1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

we could say that $A_\mu^\prime= M_{\mu}^\nu A_{\nu}$. According to my calculations:

$$M_{\mu}^\nu= \left(
\begin{matrix} -\gamma&v\gamma&0&0\\
v\gamma&\gamma&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

But according to Leonard Susskind's lectures: $M=\eta L\eta$

which doesn't agree with my calculations.

Comment: I think the problem might be in wanting to interpret expressions as $M_\mu^\nu A_\nu$ as matrix-vector products, which they are not. $$\tilde{A}_{\mu}=\eta_{\mu\nu} \tilde{A}^{\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}L^{\nu}_{\alpha}A^{\alpha}=\eta_{\mu\nu}L^{\nu}_{\alpha}\eta^{\alpha\beta}A_{\beta}=\eta_{\mu\beta}L^{\beta}_{\alpha}\eta^{\alpha\nu}A_{\nu}$$
and thus $$M_{\mu}^{\nu}=\eta_{\mu\beta}L^{\beta}_{\alpha}\eta^{\alpha\nu}.$$
Now try to figure out what matrix these components would make. If you ask me, I would try to work with components rather than matrices and only use those to display components.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka, why not make that an answer?

Comment: Thanks! I now understand the derivation but i still don´t get why my matrix assumption is wrong. I calculated $L$ using a matrix-vector multiplication consideration and it worked. Why doesn´t it work for $M$?

Comment: Never mind... I realized now what I'm doing wrong. Thank you @AdomasBaliuka